# Ruby on Rails with React getting NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, nomethoderror, react-on-rails

The following is my controller Projects#show method.

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @pm = User.find(@project.user_id)
    @employees = {}
    @supervisors = User.all.where("id = ?", Relationship.all.where("supervisor_id = ?", @project.user_id).pluck(:supervisor_id))    
    @supervisor_ids = Relationship.all.where("supervisor_id = ?",   @project.user_id).pluck(:supervisor_id)
    for supervisor in @supervisor_ids
        @employees[supervisor] = User.all.where("id = ?", Relationship.all.where("supervisor_id = ?", supervisor).pluck(:employee_id))
    end
end
```

The following is my Projects#show view html.erb file.

```
<%= react_component 'ProjectManage', { pm: @pm, supervisors: @supervisors, employees: @employees } %>
```

The following is my react front-end

```
@ProjectManage = React.createClass
    getInitialState: ->
      pm: @props.pm

    render: ->
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'org-chart'
        @props.pm.email
      for supervisor in @props.supervisors
        React.DOM.ul supervisor.email
        for employee in @props.employees[supervisor]
          React.DOM.li employee.email
```

The error message I get is:

> Completed 500 Internal Server error in ActiveRecord.
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `   ' for ProjectsController#show:0x007fa195b59da0
>
> Started GET "/projects/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-24 06:31:38 -0800
>   Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"id"=>"1"}   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
>   "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
>   Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE
>   "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT 
>   "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
>   (0.1ms)  SELECT "relationships"."supervisor_id" FROM "relationships"
>   WHERE (supervisor_id = 1)   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM
>   "users" WHERE (id = 1) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method '   ' for#):   app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:11:in `show'
>
> Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (2.7ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.1ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
>   (2.0ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout (19.6ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb
>   (0.2ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb
>   within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb
>   within layouts/javascript (22.3ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb
>   within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)   Rendered
>   /home/ferg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb
>   (34.9ms)

Comment: You should post whole error stack trace it will help you to locate line which caused error in show method

Comment: I was traveling and posted from my phone. Ill load it to my PC and get it to you.

Comment: Aparently the issue is with:@supervisors = User.all.where("id = ?", Relationship.all.where("supervisor_id = ?", @project.user_id).pluck(:supervisor_id))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were four spaces at the end of the `@supervisors` assignment. Removed trailing white space and the error is gone.